# regular expression to split up searchphrase

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I was hoping someone could help me writing a regex for c++ that matches words in a searchphrase, and explain it bit by bit for learning purposes.

What I need is a regex that matches string within `" "` like `"Hello you all"`, and single words that starts/ends with `*` like `*ack` / `overfl*`.

For the quote part I have `\"[\^\\s][\^\"]*\"` but I can't figure out the wildcard (`*`) part, and how I should combine it with the quote regex.

Comment: "I know, I'll use regex."  Now they have two problems...

Comment: "I know, I'll quote a quote about regex." Now the author has three problems because no one tells him WHY to not use regex! (Nothing personal Adam, this quote is overused IMO.)

Comment: Do you also want to match single words that don’t start/end with `*`?

Comment: @ Gumbo That would bee nice, when I wrote the question I did't think of single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
(?:\*?\w+\*?|"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*")*")+
```

For readability I replaced the backslash characters by `\x5C`.

The expression `"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*")*"` will also match `"foo \"bar\""` and other proper escaped quote sequences (but only the `"` might be escaped).

So `foo* bar *baz *quux* "foo \"bar\""` should be splitted into:

- `foo*`
- `bar`
- `*baz`
- `*quux*`
- `"foo \"bar\""`

If you don’t want to match `bar` in the example above, use this:

```
(?:\*\w+|\w+\*|"(?:[^\x5C"]+|\x5C(?:\x5C\x5C)*")*")+
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but your first regex does not work. It seems to match every single word in: 'This is a "test string"', though it ought to match '"test string"' only.

Comment: I had that before but thought he also would want to match those words too. Let’s see what Qwark says.

Comment: Vel it's monday morning and I got to test the regex at work, and it did work more perfect than I was hoping for =) , Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is no quote nesting (nesting in general is something regex is bad at):

```
"(?:(?<=\\)"|[^"])*"|\*[^\s]+|[^\s]+\*
```

This regex allows for escaped double quotes (`'\"'`), though, if you need that. And the match includes the enclosing double quotes.

This regex matches:

- `"A string in quotes, possibly containing \"escaped quotes\""`
- `*a_search_word_beginning_with_a_star`
- `a_search_word_ending_with_a_star*`
- `*a_search_word_enclosed_in_stars*`

**Be aware** that it will break at strings like this:

- `A broken \"string "with the quotes all \"mangled up\""`

If you expect (read: *can't entirely rule out the possibility*) to get these, please don't use regex, but write a small quote-aware parser. For a one-shot search and replace activity or input in a *guaranteed* format, the regex is okay to use.

For validating/parsing user input, it is not okay to use. That's where I would recommend a parser. Knowing the difference is the key.